# How to relate fields in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

In a model, I have a DecimalField "first_arg", and a multiple choice CharField "second_arg".

I'd like to achieve the following: 
In the admin panel, if a particular option (let's say "B") is selected for "second_arg" field, increment any value that is inserted to "first_arg" form field by 2. It should happen only in the UI level.
What's the right way to go about it?

Since it's part of the admin UI, modifying the model should be wrong. On the other hand, I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation. I thought about simply using some JS in a static file, but that's kinda hacky. Is there an elegant way to do these things in Django Admin?

Model code:

```
a = "a"
b = "b"
etc = "etc"
RELEVANT_OPTIONS = (
    (a, "A"),
    (b, "B"),
    (etc, "etc")
)


class MyModel(models.Model):

    first_arg = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=4,
        decimal_places=2,
        blank=True, null=True
    )
    second_arg = models.CharField(
        choices=constants.RELEVANT_OPTIONS,
        max_length=20,
        blank=True, null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure what your end goal is. Are you trying to update the UI so that the first_arg field is updated when the second_arg changes or are you looking to actually make updates to the saved first_arg field for the model?

Comment: I'm trying to update the UI, just the form field as I've written. Edited to make it clearer. Yes, I'm trying to perform an addition by a constant on "first_arg" if "second_arg" is set to a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to have to override the templates and serve some JavaScript. It is fairly extendable, which is not too "hacky" (i.e. you don't have to override the whole admin template):

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/javascript/

All the other options I am aware of would impact things on the server side.